# Require build to Contain Unit tests VSTS

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have 1 question

We use VSTS in our company. Now I want to require my developers to write unit tests to each project

My question is: If I can to build in Team Service Web Portal to require contain Unit tests, and if project doesn't has any unit tests - set build fail?

Thank you.

Comment: Does each project will only contain unit tests instead of other tests? Is it ok for you to check if each project contains unit test by check the warning in VS Test task? Such as if VS Test task shows `[warning]No test assemblies found matching the pattern: '**\*test*.dll;-:**\obj\**'`, then fail the build. Or what's other criterion do you want to use to check if project contains unit test?

Comment: Yeah - [warning]No test assemblies found matching the pattern: '**\*test*.dll;-:**\obj\**', then fail the build.  Is Enought for me.

Comment: @MarinaLiu-MSFT how i can do that?

Comment: This is a people problem, not a technology problem. What if developers add a test project that contains one test that just does `Assert.IsTrue(true)`? What if they add significant new functionality without writing new tests? What if they write bad tests that don't validate correctness? If your developers aren't on board with injecting quality into the development process, your requirement isn't going to help. If your developers *are* on board with it, your requirement is unnecessary.

Comment: @DanielMann - Yeah exactly. We already talked with our developers)

Answer (score -1):

You can add a **PowerShell task** to check if the build project contains unit tests. Detail steps as below:

Add a PowerShell task after VS test task, and get VS test build log by [timeline REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/build/timeline/get?view=vsts-rest-4.1). For TFS the rest api format should be:

```
GET http://{tsserver}:8080/tfs/{collection}/{project}/_apis/build/builds/{buildId}/timeline?api-version=3.0
```

Then search the log for VS test task, and you can get the detail VS test build log by the `url`. Such as below example, VS test task build log can be find in `http://wxv-xindo-12r2:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/5dfb8b33-9949-4187-9d09-474c8fe87238/_apis/build/builds/1477/logs/5`.

```
    {
        "id": "c43e4f8f-3db9-4fdc-90c0-1153f165b9a9",
        "parentId": "39d66172-979a-46e8-a04d-fe8e4e77da43",
        "type": "Task",
        "name": "Test Assemblies",
        "startTime": "2018-05-25T02:31:11.177Z",
        "finishTime": "2018-05-25T02:31:17.133Z",
        "currentOperation": null,
        "percentComplete": null,
        "state": "completed",
        "result": "succeeded",
        "resultCode": null,
        "changeId": 17,
        "lastModified": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
        "workerName": "mypc",
        "order": 5,
        "details": null,
        "errorCount": 0,
        "warningCount": 2,
        "url": null,
        "log": {
            "id": 5,
            "type": "Container",
            "url": "http://tfsserver:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/5dfb8b33-9949-4187-9d09-474c8fe87238/_apis/build/builds/1477/logs/5"
        },
        "task": {
            "id": "ef087383-ee5e-42c7-9a53-ab56c98420f9",
            "name": "VSTest",
            "version": "2.0.55"
        },
        "issues": [
            {
                "type": "warning",
                "category": "General",
                "message": "",
                "data": {
                    "type": "warning",
                    "code": "002004"
                }
            },
            {
                "type": "warning",
                "category": "General",
                "message": "No test assemblies found matching the pattern: **\\release\\*test*.dll,!**\\obj\\**.",
                "data": {
                    "type": "warning"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
```

Then check if the VS test task has the warning:

```
[warning]No test assemblies found matching the pattern: '**\*test*.dll;-:**\obj\**'
```

If the VS test build log contains above warning, fail the PowerShell task by `exit 1`.

Comment: I use TFS on my server and probably My Instance of TFS doesnt has API

Comment: The Timeline REST API indeed support for TFS, you just need to user lower api version such as 2.0 or 3.0. And I updated the REST API format with TFS in my answer, you can have a try.